# How to do reversed recursive iteration on a n-depth n-property php object

Tags: php, object, iteration

I got a object of n-depth and n-property number per nested object. I dont know the nesting depth or property amount of any of those objects.

I need to iterate through the object beginning from the leaves(deepest childs) back to the parent.

If anyone knows a way that does not include copying all paths into a seperate object to work through all of them i would be happy.

// EDIT
Since i wasn't specific enaugh in my question i gonne try to explain it by a data example.

Plot: My software is based on an entity relationship data model using orientdb.

So what my task is to map an entity relationship based model back into my database. Example of an "to map" object looks like following:

```
{
test : {
    server : {
        ip : {
            value : "1.2.3.4",
            port : [
                {
                    value : "80",
                    state : {
                        value : "open"
                    }
                },
                {
                    value : "443",
                    state : {
                        value : "open"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    name : {
        value : "test"
    }
}
```

}

So when i start mapping back the entities i first create all the "value" nodes. So those stay unique. Than i need to start a reversed recursion from the leaves of my nested data back to the main node to be sure i can identify unique entities and not mess up the existing information. If i would just iterate from parent to child and create the structures i dont know if the dependent childs are in the same relation contexts so i would destroy allready gathered information. Thats why i need to iterate reversed recursive from the deepest childs back to the parent to identify each of those unique entities and create those not existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it in a recursive function.  It sounds to me that you're wanting to reach the Super Parent of the base class irrespective of how far up that parent lives in the inheritance line.

I'd try something like this personally:

```
function climbToSuperParent($currentObject) {
  $parent = get_parent_class($currentObject);
  if (class_parents($parent)) {
    return $this->climbToSuperParent($parent);
  } else {
    return $parent;
  }
}
```

You can add any additional outputs in the recursion if you need, like class properties of each parent you want retrieved or a list of class parent names to get the whole inheritance line as you're inspecting each parent one by one.  Just add what you need to an array passed by reference to the same function as a second parameter.

**EDIT :** Thanks for the extra info, makes it much easier to find what you need.  I wouldn't start from the leaves as you put it, in fact you mentioned not knowing the depth of the leaves so it would be tricky.  I would just iterate through from the parent down with a recursive alogrithm again, but look for `'value'` keys as they contain the data of the fields you're looking for.  You know what the nesting can look like to cater for arrays as values and handle them in the algorithm too.  What about the following then instead:

```
function getValuesFromChildren($object, &$output = array(), $parent = null) {
foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            return $this->getValuesFromChildren($object, $output, $key);
        }
    }
    if (is_object($value)) {
        if (!empty($value->value)) {
            $output[$parent] = $value->value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The `$output` array should have your data values mapped to their names.  Didn't test this, but I think you get the idea.  I think it or something similar will work.

Comment: Probably i wasn't specific enaugh in my question. Your solution is quite well but sadly not fitting to my purpose. I will edit the question with an example so it maybe gets more comprehensable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: thx :) its not 100% what im searching for but it helps me alot :)